# opencv python decreasing gaps canny

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to draw outlines for paper. just like -> https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/

But every time I run this code, 'NameError: name 'screenCnt' is not defined' error shows.
I found out that the picture I have has a little of gap. which makes the len of the approx into 3 . just like the picture at the bottom. How can I decrease the gap of the outline.
[image]

```
image = cv2.imread('example.jpg')
ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 500)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)
edge=  auto_canny(gray)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    # if our approximated contour has four points, then we
    # can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break
# show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
print("STEP 2: Find contours of paper")
cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Outline", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Why not just threshold the image, apply some morphology to clean it up. The get the largest contour.

Comment: how can I fill gaps using morphology can you give me an example codes?

Comment: I suggest you not use Canny edges. Why not just threshold the image, apply some morphology to clean it up. Then get the largest contour.